# 'While' Loop not executing?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have a comment in my code to explain what the end result I am going towards is, but please do not answer how I could achieve that goal whilst answering this question.

Basically, I have an int labeled "currentNum" which is equal to 1. I have a while loop that is to execute until currentNum is less that four million. However, for some reason the loop is not executing. Everything outside of the while loop executes, but the while loop itself does not.

'HI' is displayed on the console once.
'LOOP' is not displayed in the console.

Code:

```
 /*Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. 
  * By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
  * 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
  * By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, 
  * find the sum of the even-valued terms.*/

public class Solution {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int lastNum1 = 0;
    int lastNum2 = 0;
    int currentNumEven = 0;
    int currentNum = 1;
    int sumEven = 0;
    boolean last = true;

    System.out.println("HI");

    while(currentNum < 4000000);

    System.out.println("LOOP");

    currentNum = currentNum + (lastNum1 + lastNum2);

    if(last) {
        lastNum1 = currentNum;
        last = !last;
    } else {
        lastNum2 = currentNum;
        last = !last;
    }

    if(currentNum % 2 == 0) {
        currentNumEven = currentNum;
        sumEven += currentNum;
        System.out.println(currentNumEven);
        System.out.println(currentNum);
    }

    if(currentNum < 4000000) {
    currentNum++;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Sum of all even Fibonacci values: " + sumEven + "\n Last even number of sequence below 4,000,000" + currentNumEven);
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: You have a semi colon after your `while` statement. You probably wanted to use braces to open a code block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
 while(currentNum < 4000000);
```

That last `;` is misplaced! after the `while` condition you should put an opening `{`, and then another `}` at the end of the loop, for closing the block. Like this:

```
while (currentNum < 4000000) {
    // body
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, how did I do that! Rather, how did I miss that? Thanks a bunch. :o

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error. Correct syntax is:

```
do{
 //put your codes here
}
while(currentNum < 4000000);
```

or

```
while(currentNum < 4000000){
//put your codes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `;` declares the end of a statement. Try this:

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int lastNum1 = 0;
    int lastNum2 = 0;
    int currentNumEven = 0;
    int currentNum = 1;
    int sumEven = 0;
    boolean last = true;

    System.out.println("HI");

    while(currentNum < 4000000){

    System.out.println("LOOP");

    currentNum = currentNum + (lastNum1 + lastNum2);

    if(last) {
        lastNum1 = currentNum;
        last = !last;
    } else {
        lastNum2 = currentNum;
        last = !last;
    }

    if(currentNum % 2 == 0) {
        currentNumEven = currentNum;
        sumEven += currentNum;
        System.out.println(currentNumEven);
        System.out.println(currentNum);
    }

    if(currentNum < 4000000) {
    currentNum++;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Sum of all even Fibonacci values: " + sumEven + "\n Last even number of sequence below 4,000,000" + currentNumEven);
      }
     }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line is where your problem is

```
while(currentNum < 4000000);
```

This causes an infinite loop because "currentNum" is never increased.

```
while(currentNum < 4000000);
```

==

```
while(currentNum < 4000000){
}
```